# how to sent any file using httprequest plugin jenkins

Tags: jenkins, httprequest, cobol, jcl

How can we send the contents of a file (JCL - Cobol) from the Jenkins server that is on Linux to another server. We are having disadvantages because the HTTP Request plug-in is not taking the file indicated in the path.

Please help with the subject. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add the code you already tried, and provide more context about your problem.

Comment: Could you tell me some script example that I should put in the http request body? I am new to this and it is really urgently needed. Thank you

Comment: You are saying you are having issues with sending the contents of a file, include the code you have done, and any context information that might be needed, for example when you say `the HTTP Request plug-in is not taking the file indicated in the path` what do you mean? what's the response?